# Testing a React-redux component with a service on it's instance with React testing library

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-testing-library

I have a component which gets 90% of it's props from my Redux store.
It has a service on it's instance which is responsible for fetching, parsing and caching PDF's.

What I used to do in Enzyme is mock out the service because I don't want to make these calls in my tests since I test my service in isolation. So I just check if the proper methods on that service are called.

I can mingle with the prototype a bit to achieve the same thing in my component mount. However, the only thing that can trigger the actions in my update are my redux props

```
  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    const { pageNumbersToShow, answersToShow } = this.props; // All from redux
    const { pageNumbersToShow: prevPages, answersToShow: prevAnswers } = prevProps;

    const navigationOccurred = pageNumbersToShow !== prevPages;
    const answerVisibilityChanged = answersToShow.some((value, index) => value !== prevAnswers[index])
      || prevAnswers.some((value, index) => value !== answersToShow[index]);

    this.setPages(navigationOccurred, answerVisibilityChanged);
  }
```

the setPages does the following and this new state is given to an underlying component.

```
setPages(bookChanged, answersChanged) {
    const promises = [];

    promises.push(bookChanged ? this.getPages() : Promise.resolve());
    promises.push(answersChanged ? this.getAnswerPages() : Promise.resolve());

    Promise.all(promises)
      .then(([bookPages, answerPages]) => {
        const newState = {};

        if (bookPages) newState.bookPages = bookPages;
        if (answerPages) newState.answerPages = answerPages;

        if (isLastUpdate()) {
          this.setState(newState);
        }
      })
      .catch(err => {
        this.setState({ err });
      });
  }
```

So what I basically want to check in the end is if the Underlying component is called with the new state which I return in my mocked service.